# Im getting a different output than expected when using df.loc to change some values of the df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a data frame, and I want to assign a quartile number based on the *quartile* variable, which gives me the ranges that I later use in the for. The problem is that instead of just changing the quartile number, it its creating n (len of the datframe) rows, and then using the row number for the loop.

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygfbq.png)
[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unIes.png)

```
quartile = numpy.quantile(pivot['AHT'], [0.25,0.5,0.75])
pivot['Quartile'] = 0

for i in range(0,len(pivot)-1):

if i <= quartile[0]:
    pivot.loc[i,'Quartile'] = 1
    

elif i <= quartile[1]:
    pivot.loc[i,'Quartile'] = 2


elif i <= quartile[2]:
    pivot.loc[i,'Quartile'] = 3
    
    
else:
    pivot.loc[i,'Quartile'] = 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) with `labels=False` and add `1` or specify values of labels in list:

```
pivot['Quartile'] = pd.qcut(pivot['AHT'], 4, labels=False) + 1
```

---

```
pivot['Quartile'] = pd.qcut(pivot['AHT'], 4, labels=[1,2,3,4])
```